# Let $G$ be a group. If order of the element in the group $G$ is prime

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. If order of the element in the group $G$ is prime ($G$ is not a $p$-group, order of the elements are different prime). Is $G$ is solvable?

Comment: Do you mean every element in $G$ has order $p_i$ for possibly distinct primes $p_i$?

Comment: Yes. They are having order prime, but not the same prime. Some elements may have order $p_1$, some may have order $p_2$.

Comment: Please show your attempts!

Comment: Can you give an example of such a group? Not a $p$-group, so there are elements of distinct prime order, but every nontrivial element has prime order?

Comment: $S_3$ is an example of such type of group.

Comment: Sigh; of course it is, and of course $A_5$ is a counterexample. It's clearly too late here and I need to go to sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternating group $A_5$ is simple (and so not solvable), but every non-trivial element has order 2, 3, or 5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it is so then can we say that all the elements of order $p$ are in the same conjugacy class. What can we say about the conjugacy classes of the group.

Comment: [Here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A5#Conjugacy_class_structure) is the conjugacy class structure of $A_5$. As you can see, not all elements of order 5 are conjugate.

Comment: Is it true in general? That means if order of all the elements of the group is prime, then is it true that all the elements of order $p$ are in the same conjugacy class?

Comment: I just gave you an example where it's not true.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.